# Is it possible to use regexp in Inno Setup?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, inno-setup

I would like to filter some file in directory.

For example I have directory "MyDir" with 2 files and 1 dir:

1. foo.doc
2. foo.mp3
3. file.txt
4. file.properties
5. dir

   3.1 foodir.pk
    3.2 foodir.txt

I need to define files in one expression:

1. not ".doc"
2. not ".mp3"
3. not "dir\".

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot use regular expressions in Inno Setup.

But you do not need them for your task, just use plain wildcards:

```
[Files]
Source: "*.*"; Excludes: "*.doc, *.mp3, dir"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
```

See [[Files] section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection) in Inno Setup documentation.

---

Though you cannot use any kind of exclude mask/pattern in `[UninstallDelete]` and `[InstallDelete]` sections.

It's for a good reason. You should only delete files you explicitly choose to delete. Not delete all files, only choosing few files you do not want to delete.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at: 
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/ir9Ex/20120322/1332397961

This particular implementation uses VB RegExp, searching for strings containing.

---

Update:
Yes and No, not directly

```pascal
{=============================================================================}
{* Global and case insensitive search.                                        }
{* Usage:  <file>, <search>, <replace/return>                                 }
function regExpFile( FileName, RE_Pattern, RE_Replace: ansiString ): string;
var
  RegExp: variant;
  CntIn, CntOut: longint;
  TextRowInAll: tArrayOfString;
  TextRowInNum: longint;
  TextRowIn: ansiString;
  TextRowOut: variant;
  TextRowOutAll: ansiString;  //* Container for the returned string.
begin
  Result := '';  { No matches yet. }
  TextRowOutAll := '';  { Default return string. }
  CntOut := 0;
  try
    RegExp := createOleObject( 'VBScript.RegExp' );
  except
    raiseException('VBScript RegExp is required to complete the post-installation process.'#13#10#13#10'(Error: ' + GetExceptionMessage);
  end;
  RegExp.Pattern := RE_Pattern;
  RegExp.Global := TRUE;
  RegExp.IgnoreCase := TRUE;
  if loadStringsFromFile( FileName, TextRowInAll ) then begin
    TextRowInNum := getArrayLength( TextRowInAll );
    for CntIn := 0 to (TextRowInNum - 1) do begin
      TextRowIn := TextRowInAll[ CntIn ];
      if RegExp.Test( TextRowIn ) then begin  { match or nothing... }
        TextRowOut := RegExp.Replace( TextRowIn, RE_Replace );
        if not varIsClear( TextRowOut ) then begin  { At least one match. }
          if CntOut < 1 then begin
            TextRowOutAll := TextRowOut;
          end
          else begin
            TextRowOutAll := TextRowOutAll + #13#10 + TextRowOut;
          end;
          CntOut := CntOut + 1;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := TextRowOutAll;
end;
{ Ex. Search for and return the numbers only from the string: "...Version: 5.8..." }
{ RE_Pattern := '(.*version.*)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(.*)'; }
{ RE_Replace := '[$2]'; }
{ Deps:  VBScript.RegExp }
{ 20160828 }
{ (Inspiration) Trackback - http://d.hatena.ne.jp/ir9Ex/20120322/1332397961 }
{ Microsoft Beefs Up VBScript with Regular Expressions - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx }
{ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- }
```

Comment: It may answer the question but essential part should be here.

Comment: This code causes an exception "unknown method".
See this link for more details http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=30809&group=jrsoftware.innosetup.code#30809